# Div is not taking the full height of its parent positioned with `vh` unite?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I must say that this isn't kind of a big problem, but it is weird though!

I have a `section` element with `min-height: 50vh;` *css*. And inside it a div with some contents. Even after setting `height: 100%;` to the `div`, it still doesn't take the full height of its parent; the `section`.
And that is what I don't see why!?!

One solution is to give a relative position to the`section` and absolute to the `div` with `top, bottom, left, and right` set to `0`. But I'm super anxious to know why did that behaviour happen?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A block display element (which a div is) will take up the full width of its parent, but it will ***not*** take the full height of it's parent. By default, the height of a block display element is defined by the height of its contents.

If you do want your div to take up the full height relative to the parent container, you can explicitly set it's height in CSS. If you set the height to 100% then it will in fact take the full height of it's parent, regardless it's children.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

That's so true that the div takes the full width of its parent, but the height of its content. My intention was writing `height` instead of `width` and that in place missed up what I was trying to ask(will fix my post now). Thank you for the correction.

Comment: It is because your parent container does not have a defined height. Only a min-height. If you set your section tag to have a height of 50vh instead of min-height, you will see the child content behave as you would expect.

This is always going to be a trick in CSS. If the parent does not have a height defined, then you cannot define the height of a child element in percentage. So if you want to have a 100% height div (and not use viewport relative units like vh), then you have to define the html and body tags to 100% height. Then your root div can also be defined at 100%.